# how can i hide a label in a aspx file and show the same label when onclick event fires on the codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My aspx code for label will be like below. I want the label to disabled by default.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ErroMsg" Text="User id or password is wrong" CssClass="labelHide"></asp:Label>
```

Wrong userid/password provided scenarion on the code behind, i want to enable this label.

```
     protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        If (login= <correct user id/password supplied>)

        }
      else
        {
              // if wrong user id/password supplied
                ErroMsg.CssClass = "lablesShow";
                ErroMsg.Text += ErroMsg.Text.ToString();

        }
```

My css values will be like below

```
.labelHide {
    display: none;
}
.labelShow {
    display: block;   
}
```

what wrong with my code? my label is not hide by default :(

Comment: Why don't you use `ErroMsg.Visible = true;` and you use CSS instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ErroMsg" 
    Text="User id or password is wrong" CssClass="labelHide" Visible = "false">
</asp:Label>
```

and in codebehind

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (/*If correct user id/password supplied*/)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        ErroMsg.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

**OR**

keep the same `mark-up` and place this

```
ErroMsg.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

or this

```
ErroMsg.Attributes["class"] = "labelShow";
```

in `else` part of code-behind.

Comment: You have undone the changes I made to your c# code block, and this does not compile. See the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26491402/revisions)

Comment: @Selva yes. use this in code behind. your aspx.cs page.

Comment: Thanks gunr2171, that was done by mistake as I was giving OP more option. So this is not the reason to get angry and vote-down.

Comment: I removed my downvote when you fixed it. Just keep in mind about edit colisions. Side note: Instead of using an `else` you can just do `if(!correct) { ErroMsg.Visible = true ; }`.

Comment: Thnk you sir, it was OP's code and I thought he would be more comfirtable with his own code :)

Comment: Hi @lmad, When i was using ErroMsg.Attributes("class") = "labelShow"; in my code behind it says an error "method,delegate or event is expected" Kindly help.

Comment: try this ErroMsg.Attributes.Add("class", "labelShow")